# Why cant I access class variable from one of it's method as below in Python?

Tags: python, class-variables

I made a class named 'employee' as below. I can access the class variable 'company' directly through class itself but cant access it using 'getCompany()' method. What is wrong with my code? Since I am newbie to OOP concepts, please **grant me detailed but step-wise elaboration** of the concepts.

```
<!-- language: lang-python -->

>>> class employee:
    company = 'ABC Corporation'
    def getCompany():
        return company

>>> employee.company       #####this does as expected
'ABC Corporation'
>>> employee.getCompany()  #####what is wrong with this thing???
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
     employee.getCompany()
   File "<pyshell#13>", line 4, in getCompany
     return company
NameError: name 'company' is not defined   #####says it is not defined
```

### I am newbie to OOP concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpreter is looking for a local variable of that name, which doesn't exist. You should also add `self` to the parameters, so that you have a proper instance method. If you want a static method instead of an instance method, you'll need to add the `@staticmethod` decorator. Finally, use the class name to refer to the class variable.

```
>>> class employee:
...     company = 'ABC Corporation'
...     def getCompany(self=None):
...             return employee.company
...
>>> employee.company
'ABC Corporation'
>>> employee.getCompany()
'ABC Corporation'
>>> e = employee()
>>> e.getCompany()
'ABC Corporation'
>>> e.company
'ABC Corporation'
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it. The main point was that the 'company' variable was not defined within the method. And we cant simply access the class variable only by class variable name.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: class employee:
   ...:     company = "ABC Corporation"
   ...:     def getCompany(self):
   ...:         return self.company
   ...:

In [2]: employee.company
Out[2]: 'ABC Corporation'

In [3]: employee().getCompany()
Out[3]: 'ABC Corporation'

In [4]: class employee:
   ...:     company = "ABC Corporation"
   ...:
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def getCompany(self):
   ...:         return self.company
   ...:

In [5]: employee.company
Out[5]: 'ABC Corporation'

In [6]: employee.getCompany()
Out[6]: 'ABC Corporation'
```

---

Question [Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python) has more details